# Firebase Data Modeling

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database, nosql

I am at the beginning stages of creating a practice app.

My data model is something like this:

This is an example of a `userObject` with a `unique identifier` of `j3kl4j3kl`.

This is a one to one relationship btw. One user has one todo list and vice versa.

```
userObject {
    j3kl4j3kl {
        provider: facebook
        username: john
        todoList: j34kl5j43kl
    }
}

todoList {
    j34kl5j43kl {
        user: j3kl4j3kl
        houseWork {
            chore1: clean garage
        }
        garden {
            chore1: take out weeds
        }
    }
}
```

My question is for the `todoList` key for this specific user should I make the Todo List a separate object similar to the one below or should I just add that todoList structure to the `todoList` key under the user object.

Comment: It seems like a good structure to start with. But in general when using a NoSQL database, your data model will depend on how you want to access the data. So expect for the model to evolve as you're discovering your app's use-cases. Read this great primer on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)

Comment: Arite makes sense!

Comment: Like Frank said, it will really depend on your use-cases, but considering it's a todo list app, I'm assuming your use-cases will mostly involve accessing the `user` node first then accessing the corresponding `todoList` node.

If that really is the case, it would make sense to just have the `todoList` as a node under the `user` node. 

One use-case where it would make sense to separate them would be if you want to display all your users' todoLists in some view.

Comment: @NishantRoy Yes exactly that is what I am going to do. So it would make sense to make the todo list object separate so when I download the user object I do not have to download the entire to do list object correct? Also I am planning to display the users' todolist list on a view as well as you stated.

Comment: What exactly is your use-case? You want to show the user that is logged in his/her todoList? Or do you want to display the todoList of EVERY user in the system?

Comment: Basically I will have a view for the current user to create his or her todo list when signing up (so during sign up I make the user create their own todo list and save that to firebase). And when another user searches for that specific user, they should be able to view their todo list. Also on the my profile page the current user should be able to see his or her todo list. I realized this is all over the place haha...

Comment: Well firstly think about the privacy factor of showing the other user's todoList.

But you could just have the todoLists be a separate object, look at the user object, look at the todoList key for them, iterate through the todoLists object and select the matching one.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was going to do. This isn't a legit app or anything just a quick simple app to test some things out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Gotcha. Yea then just have the 2 separate objects and you should be fine.